# Como desativar o sistema de rotas do angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routes

Tenho um projeto desenvolvido em angular 1, estou utilizando routeProvider e locationProvider. Porém agora que o projeto está "pronto", preciso desativar o sistema de rotas, ou seja, quando a URL for alterada, quando eu acessar outra página, preciso que a página seja recarregada novamente.

Alguém já precisou desativar as rotas para fazer algo semelhante?

Segue abaixo o sistema de rotas que utilizo no routes.js das páginas:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
.module('solicitardocumentos')
.config(Config);

function Config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/solicitardocumentos', {
        templateUrl: 'modulosolicitardocumentos/template/index.html',
        controller: 'solicitardocumentosController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');

}
```

})();

Comment: Talvez não tenha ficado claro exatamente o que você deseja, Maurício. Por 'desativar o sistema de rotas', o que você quer dizer? Você só tem uma rota. Você não deseja mais que esta rota seja alcançada se o usuário digitar 'sistema/#/solicitardocumentos'? Qual seria o comportamento desejado?

Comment: Meu site contém 5 páginas, o que quero dizer é que quando eu alterar de uma página para outra, o site deverá ser totalmente carregado novamente. O que eu acredito que seja algo que deve ser feito dentro do routes.

Comment: Eu pergunto porque se você está usando um framework SPA (single page application) a idéia é que você não navegue/recarregue o browser a cada mudança - você apenas altera estados (states).

Comment: Infelizmente o cliente solicitou o carregamento individual das páginas agora que o projeto está pronto :(, por isso que gostaria se seria simples de alterar isto.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com recarregar a página? Quando você troca de página, o controller do angular (dentro de um arquivo **.js**) é executado novamente, logo os dados são *recarregados*. Agora, se a questão é recarregar o html inteiro, acredito que isso não seja possível, pois isso é um **arquivo estático** (tal como **.js** e **.css**) que o browser pode guardar em cache (dependendo de suas configurações). Isso é diferente de uma página **.php** ou **.cshtml** que o browser não interpreta como sendo estático, logo ele não faz cache disso, sendo toda vez requisitado ao server novamente.

Answer (score -3):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
 
@Component({
   templateUrl: './login.component.html',
   styles: [``]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit { 
 
    invalidCredentialMsg: string;
    username:string;
    password:string;
    retUrl:string="home";
 
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, 
                private router: Router, 
                private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) {
    }
 
    ngOnInit() {
        this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap
                .subscribe(params => {
            this.retUrl = params.get('retUrl'); 
            console.log( 'LoginComponent/ngOnInit '+ this.retUrl);
        });
    }
 
    onFormSubmit(loginForm) {
       this.authService.login(loginForm.value.username, loginForm.value.password).subscribe(data => {
           console.log( 'return to '+ this.retUrl);
           if (this.retUrl!=null) {
                this.router.navigate( [this.retUrl]);
           } else {
                this.router.navigate( ['home']);
           }
       });
    }
}
```